# R: Append matrix rows if condition is met

Tags: r, loops, matrix, indexing, append

I loop through a matrix and I would like to append a matrix row to another empty matrix if a specific condition is met. How do I do this without getting problems with the different indexes?
I had this code, but my dataset is very large, so I get problems in the implementation

```
for (i in 1:length(matrix1)) {
    if ((substr(matrix1[i,1],6,7) == '02') == TRUE) {
        for (j in 1:nrow(matrix2)) {
            matrix2[j,] <- matrix1[i,]
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient solution?

`dput(matrix1[1])` is `c("271", "269", "274", "278", "293", "270", "274", "274", "275",  "271", "2018-01-03_0445")`

`nrow(matrix1)` is `400000`

Comment: better provide the data for `matrix1`

Comment: (1) You say _"append"_ but `matrix2[j,] <-` is _assignment_. If you want to append rows, `rbind` seems like what you need. (2) I'm inferring that you want to append the row once, but your `matrix1[i,]` is being added `j`-times (number of rows in `matrix2`). In addition to adding the sample data that ThomasIsCoding requested, I think you should also include your expected output given that sample data. We don't need big matrices, perhaps just 5-10 rows (some matches, some not) and 2-3 columns. When using `dput`, please give us all of it, not just a portion, perhaps `dput(matrix1[1:10,1:3])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply extract the rows satisfying your condition:

```
matrix2 <- matrix1[substr(matrix1[, 1], 6, 7) == '02', ]
```